# Gson: enum serialization issue in bean

Tags: java, serialization, enums, gson

My SegmentCreateRequest bean class:

```
public class SegmentCreateRequest {

    @SerializedName("name")
    private String segmentName;

    private SegmentSource segmentSource;

    public String getSegmentName() {
        return segmentName;
    }

    public void setSegmentName(String segmentName) {
        this.segmentName = segmentName;
    }

    public SegmentSource getSegmentSource() {
        return segmentSource;
    }

    public void setSegmentSource(SegmentSource segmentSource) {
        this.segmentSource = segmentSource;
    }

    public enum SegmentSource {

        @SerializedName("followed") FOLLOWED,
        @SerializedName("impressed") IMPRESSED,
        @SerializedName("engaged") ENGAGED,
        @SerializedName("tailored") TAILORED;

        @SerializedName("user_ids")
        private List<String> userIds;

        SegmentSource(){
            this.userIds = Lists.newArrayList();
        }

        public void setUserIds(List<String> userIds) {
            this.userIds = userIds;
        }

        public List<String> getUserIds() {
            return this.userIds;
        }

        public SegmentSource userIds(List<String> userIds) {
            this.userIds = userIds;
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

The `segmentSource` field name should change according to the value of the enum.

I was expecting object serialization of this class to return something like:

```
{
 "name":"segment101",
 "followed":{"user_ids":["1234567890"]}
}
```

However, it returns:

```
{"name":"skumar-3020-seg","segmentSource":"followed"}
```

using Google Gson for serialization/deserialization.

How do I setup my bean to achieve the required serialization?

Comment: Thanks for the accept; glad my answer was helpful to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are serializing an enum instance into a **field** named **segmentSource**.

The name of that field is **not** name!

Beyond that, there is also a potential bug in your code: enums are singeltons! There will be **one** instance of FOLLOWED for example. This means: any change to the list of FOLLOWED is visible "globally". There is no such thing as having *two* different SegmentCreateRequests then (in parallel).

In other words: when you create some

```
SegmentCreateRequests reqA = ...
```

with some specific users on FOLLOWED; but you do

```
SegmentCreateRequests reqB = ...
```

in parallel, then those two requests objects will be working on the **same** list in the end. Meaning: your code isn't thread safe. Thus: that list of users **must** not go into the enum constant. It should rather be a property of the surrounding request!

Comment: Apart of that, Gson does not support `@SerializedName` on enums for such a scenario (and I think that it should never be, however I find the following issue strange: https://github.com/google/gson/issues/1011 ). Dynamic names are not supported too (`FieldNamingStrategy` does not provide actual field values). The OP must redesign the DTO in any case.